# Extract audio file using mencoder

Tags: ffmpeg, mencoder

I have a mp4 file and I want to extract the audio. (preferably in flac format.)

I can do it with ffmpeg command:

```
$ ffmpeg -i infilename.mp4 -acodec flac outfilename.flac
```

Unfortunately, my Ubuntu 14.04 does not have ffmpeg command, and have mencoder command instead.

My question is how can I extract audio from movie files with mencoder command?

Comment: Why not just get a [static build of `ffmpeg`](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/)?

Comment: you could use "avconv" instead [a now distant fork of FFmpeg], or mencoder -vn or something like that.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/432542/is-ffmpeg-missing-from-the-official-repositories-in-14-04